# ui.router not working. Not sure what is going on

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I am trying to replace ngRoute with ui-router so I can use multiple views

In my template file I have `<div ui-view></div>`

then in my app file I have

```
angular.module('myApp', [
    'ui.router',
    //'signup',
    'myApp.controllers',
    'myApp.filters',
    'myApp.services',
    'myApp.directives'
]).config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });

        $stateProvider.
            state('/', {
                url: '/',
                templateUrl: '/partials/homepage',
                controller: 'MyCtrl1'
            }).
            state('about.detail', {
                url: '/about/:id',
                templateUrl: function(params){
                    return '/partials/about/'+params.id
                },
                controller: 'MyCtrl1'
            }).
            state('funnel', {
                url: '/funnel',
                templateUrl: '/partials/funnel',
                controller: 'MyCtrl2'
            });

        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    });
```

For some reason, these routes are not picking up if I go to them directly  like /funnel

Do I have this setup right to pickup a route if I goto localhost:3000/funnel?

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using html5mode and not hashbangs you will need to add a redirect in your .htaccess to send everything back to your root index.html. Without it, you are trying to find a directory that doesn't exist. Here is what I use:

```
RewriteEngine   On
RewriteBase     /
RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/index\.php|/img|/js|/css|/robots\.txt|/favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule     . /index.html [L]
```

Comment: I am using a node and express backend.  There is no index file

Comment: I should have picked up on that from :3000. It looks like this blog post may answer your question but I haven't tested it so I won't add it as an answer: http://heu.io/posts/push-state-with-nodejs-and-express/